# How to Edit the Template for the Odoo Helpdesk Ticket Assigned Message

Tags: email, templates, odoo, trouble-tickets

I'm currently using Odoo 12.0+e-20181025. I'm trying to edit the message the user get whenever a ticket is assigned to them. I've tried searching the email template, but I can't find it. I've also tried searching in the main folder, but I still can't find it. As of now, I only managed to make a similar template, but I also found some trouble in that task as I can't really emulate the button that can link right to the ticket editing form, only to the preview ticket window.

Here is the code for the link to the ticket:

`<a href="http://158.140.187.28:8069/helpdesk/ticket/${object.id}/${object.access_token}" style="text-decoration-thickness:auto;background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">${object.name}</a> .​`

While knowing how to make a proper link will help a lot, I would still prefer to know where I can edit the message template so I can make it more user friendly and informative.

Thanks for reading and for the help.